# Get account information based on last login time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    c.* ,concat ( s.FirstName,'',s.LastName) as FullName
FROM [dbo].[Monitor] c
left join acc.Staff s on s.Id = c.UserId where c.UserId=1
```

Results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibENy.png)

How to get account information based on last login time in SQL Server.

I don't know how to get account information based on last login time.

Comment: Remove C# and html tags if the question has nothing to do with those topics or add explanation what do those 2 topics have to do with your question. Also, give us what result you are getting with the query shown and also expected result, so we can help

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to query the very last login.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Monitor m Join Staff s on s.Id = m.UserId
    WHERE Object = 'Login' ORDER BY AccessDate Desc
```

Here is an explanation of the code.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Monitor m
```

The code above is going to query only 1 result (**TOP 1**) and show all the columns (*) from the table Monitor. If you wish to get only specific columns, you can change * to whatever columns needed. I've given the table Monitor the alias **m**, because the word starts with that letter, but you can name your alias however you please, for as long as you remember it, or it's easy to realize what column it refers to.

```
Join Staff s ON s.Id = m.UserID
```

I've used **Join**, because you haven't really specified what exact result you are expecting, your question is more about getting the last login, so whatever join is used depends on your expectations. The same goes with the columns I've joined the two tables on. I just copied yours, but they would depend on demanded result and obviously if you have a foreign key in any of the tables, then use that key to join them.

```
WHERE Object = 'Login' ORDER BY AccessDate DESC
```

This is the important part of the code for your question. By specifying that we only need rows **WHERE** the column **Object** has value of **'Login'**, we are making sure that only **Logins**, are shown and all the **Logouts** are excluded. With `ORDER BY AccessDate DESC`, we are making sure that the biggest date value is at the top. The way dates work in **SQL Server**, if you compare two dates, the later date is considered bigger, so the last login would be at the very top, and since we have `SELECT TOP 1` at the beginning we are making sure that we are going to get only the very last row.